# C# - Place a picturebox on top of another picturebox in design view

Tags: c#, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

The full question is in the heading. Using Winforms, with standard controls in Visual Studio I try to drag it on top of another picturebox but it won't allow me to place two controls in one cell of my table layout panel.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific. Is this Winforms, WPF, Webforms? are you using just standard .net controls or are you using 3rd party?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk Winforms. Standard controls in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add multiple controls to one cell. If you add another container in your cell and add the items to that container it should be no problem.

Or if you create a custom control that holds you two pictureboxes you can add this to your cell.

Comment: Thanks. I placed a panel and then added the pictureboxes and dock style = fill and all seems great. One problem. I need the order to be pbx1 at top, pbx2 at second from top. Cannot seem to select the picturebox that is not on top, to bring it to the second from the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can at first drop panel compnonent on cell. And then drop two pictureboxes on that panel.

Comment: Thanks. Still struggling to get the picturebox onto the panel. Might be worth noting the panel has a columnspan of 6.